# IOS-Ipad native application responsive design

Tags: ios, ipad, layout, responsive-design

I have an application that has many screens with many different widgets. I want to implement the best approach for applying a responsive design type technique when the orientation changes. What are the best practices for achieving the goal?

Sample of what I would like to achieve:

Landscape:
[image]
Portrait:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would probably be to use a

```
UICollectionView
```

with different

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayouts
```

for portrait and landscape.
This way you can achieve your given design with relatively small amounts of work.

If you need any help with that take a look at http://www.raywenderlich.com/22324/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-12